# Remove unnecessary jobs from build pipeline on Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, plugins, pipeline, build-pipeline-plugin

I'm a bit new to  Jenkins and I'm having an display issue with Build Pipeline plugin. I'm executing some jobs in parallel using JobFanIn Plugin, i.e. the next job in the pipeline will only be executed when all the previous jobs are concluded. However, the Build Plugin believes that all jobs will trigger a new instance of the last job. The execution goes right, but the display isn't.

Bellow is possible to observe what is happening in practice. The GENERATE TEST REPORT job will only be triggered when all TEST jobs are finished and this occurs ok. But since the Build Pipeline plugin expects 3 instances of this job to happen, only one happens and the others appeat as pending forever.Any ideas?

[First image displaying what is happening](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XFppP.png)

[Second image displaying what is supposed to happen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sfGNA.png)

Comment: if you're new to jenkins *and* you've installed a new jenkins instance, you should try out declarative pipelines instead of the build pipeline plugin. if it's an existing jenkins server and it's an old version or if the admin doesn't have the pipeline plugins installed, i understand.

Comment: It is an old instance and I don't have autonomy to do lot of stuff